# How to copy save game data of Kenny's Adventure into another computer?

Tags: kennys-adventure

I have a new computer, and need to copy my save game data across from Kenny's Adventure. Because I've got very far in that game, starting from scratch is **not** a solution.

I've copy-pasted the game's entire folder from Program Files, but I only got the Hungarian translation, but not my save game data.

Certainly, I looked at other folders too, but didn't see anything else belonging to the game. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try using FileMon/ProcessMonitor on the old computer, loading up the saved game, and then looking at the list of files accessed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later today. Anyway, I think this should be an answer, so I can accept it and award the bounty if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it stores player (and presumably saved-game) info in `C:\Program Files\Kennys Adventure\Game.bin`. I'm basing this on the trial version from http://www.divogames.com/content/games/en/files/kenny/kenny_adventure_demo.exe

Comment: Yeah, the solution was to reinstall Kenny's Adventure and overwrite that file **before** the first start. :)

Answer (score 0):

Many games save your data in the `My Documents` folder, either in a Folder named after the Game or Publisher, or in a subfolder of `My Games`.

Comment: I didn't found anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in Application Data folder? Games occasionally save things in there.

Type %APPDATA% into your explorer window to go there.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that too, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places for application data on a Windows XP system (making assumptions here).

%APPDATA% has already been mentioned, which should take you to the folder

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{user name}\Application Data
```

If it's not there (check for the company name DivoGames or some derivative of it) you can look in the following directory.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{user name}\Local Settings\Application Data
```

Remember to also go to Tools->Folder Options->View->Show Hidden Files and Folders

If it's not in those two places then its somewhere in the registry, or its obscurly named and you will have to use something like [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), as previously mentioned, to deduce it. But I would almost guarantee you that your game data is in one of those two directories if you didn't explicitly save it somewhere else or used a game service like Steam or GameTap or something.